# void wordMatch function to compare strings in a 2D array with input string

Tags: c

I'm having trouble creating a class that compares the strings in a 2D array with an input string. If one of the input strings matches is supposed to print "Match found" and if not print "match not found"

right now I have:

```
void wordMatch(char strings[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH], char input[STRING_LENGTH]) {
    char* p = &strings[0][0];
    char* ip = input;
    int flag = 0;
}
```

Comment: start with a simpler problem and then work up. first write an app to print "Hello World". Then add the ability to accept an input string. Then add the ability to pass that string into a function and print it.

Comment: What trouble are you having? I see no sign of trying. To loop through the `strings` array, use `for()`. To compare strings, use `strcmp`. To print, use `printf()`.